# Invalid Conversion error

Tags: vb.net

I recently upgraded a VB 6 project to .net. I'm having a problem  with this block of code:

```
    Dim CtrlName As System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem

    For Each CtrlName In Form1.Controls

    'Some code here

    Next CtrlName
```

Now this code compiles but throws the following runtime error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.

I have a panel control on the subject form. How do I resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating over **all** controls that are directly inside the form, not just the `MenuItem`s. However, your variable is of type `MenuItem`. This is causing the problem.

For *normal* controls (e.g. `Button`s), you’d want to use the following, easy fix; test inside the loop whether the control type is correct:

```
For Each control As Control In Form1.Controls
    Dim btt As Button = TryCast(control, Button)
    If btt IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Perform action
    End If
Next
```

However, this does *not* work for `MenuItem`s since these aren’t controls at all in WinForms, and they aren’t stored in the form’s `Controls` collection.

You need to iterate over the form’s [`Menu.MenuItems` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.menu.aspx) instead.

Comment: The "control" variable needs to be of type Object to get this to work

Comment: @IainHoult No, that’s not true. `Form1.Controls` is of type `ControlCollection` and every element in it will be a `Control`. Even though `ControlCollection` only inherits from the non-generic `ControlCollection`, you *can* iterate through it using a `Control` variable.

Comment: I put your code into Visual Studio and it gave me the following error on the TryCast: "Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem'".  It's ok for something like a Button control but not a MenuItem ?!?

Comment: @Iain Duh. I didn’t pay attention to the type of object because I assumed that the OP’s code was essentially correct. Now I see that it’s not: the `MenuItem`s are not in the form’s control collection – simple, they aren’t `Control`s.

Answer (score 1):

The items in the `Controls` property of a form, which may or may not be `MenuItem`. Assuming that you just want to iterate over `MenuItem` objects you can change your code to:

```
For Each menuControl As MenuItem In Me.Controls.OfType(Of MenuItem)
  ' Some code
Next
```

Note that the `menuControl` variable is declared in the `For` so is only accessible within the block and is disposed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
for each ctrl as control in me.controls
 if typeof ctrl is menuitem then
   ' do stuff here
 end if
next
```

typeof keyword allows you to test the type of control being examined in the control collection.

Found the answer after a bit of research, you need to search for the menu strip first and then loop through the items collection.

```
 For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf ctrl Is MenuStrip Then
            Dim mnu As MenuStrip = DirectCast(ctrl, MenuStrip)
            For Each x As ToolStripMenuItem In mnu.Items
                Debug.Print(x.Name)
            Next    
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: This code does essentially the same as mine, only worse (you still need to cast after the `TypeOf` test, and `TypeOf` + cast is replaced by `TryCast`). Regardless of this, your code fails for the same reason that mine does: menu items aren’t stored in the form’s controls collection.